# og:url is driving me crazy?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

hope you can help me...

I want to have a page with facebook metatags, like:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="TITULO" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />       
<meta property="og:image" content="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/277072_61646342824_993843268_n.jpg" />      
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.clarin.com" />
```

and the problem is that instead of showing the descriptions, titles and images that I define in the metatags of my page, the facebook like box is generated with the url defined in my `og:url`. I was reading documentation and it seems that it should be in that way.

But I still want the facebook like box generated only with the metatags of my page, and not with the url defined in `og:url`.

is it possible? someone has done?

Answer (score 65):

og:url basically tells the FB scraper "ignore anything on this page, and scrape this url instead"
So it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. If you want the like button to point to a different url, use the `href` parameter and have it point to a different url.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ for more information.

Comment: thanks you so mucho for your reply. it helps me su much.
but, i still have a problem. look the following url:
http://www.republicarayada.com.mx/test2.php

if you put it on the facebook object debugger, it's ok. it displays the correct information for my open graph tags.
but if you put it in the browser, and click into "like" button, you can see it's generating info from the href parameter!

i don't understand why. can you help me?

Comment: Because you're telling the like button to pull the information from the url in the href parameter.

Comment: @andufo I believe so, I don't know why they didn't use that instead.

Comment: also, fb scraper sometimes has it's own cache, so it's possible that he would not see your edits. Drove me crazy other day <.<

Answer (score 7):

I think I understand what you are asking. Like @Jeff Sherlock said "og:url basically tells our scraper "ignore anything on this page, and scrape this url instead"..."

So if og:url is anything other than the current page -- Facebook will try to scrape the open graph data from there instead.

If this is a page you are trying to send people to if they click on the 'like object' that is posted to a users wall (who has already liked your page) --

I made a tool for this exact purpose -- as I thought it might be helpful to others:

[Facebook/Open Graph Like button Generator](http://o-e.us/fb/lbg)

It generates (and stores) the open graph tag(s) so you don't need to put them in your page at all and the 'Redirect URL' tells it where to send all the traffic.

It detects the Facebook bot/scraper too so it won't interfere with anything :)

Good luck

Comment: How are you setting up the redirect?

Comment: if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" or $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "facebookexternalhit/1.0 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)") {
//keep facebook bots on this page for og data
}
else {
//redirect user to wherever we want
header("Location: $theredirecturl");
}

Answer (score 0):

you can put the like button in an iframe. Furthermore, that iframe may or may not need to be filled by setting a src attribute. I would try adding the like button code as innerHTML, and then try a separate file to set the src to.

It would look something like this:

```
<iframe><place like code here></iframe>
```

When that doesn't work, place the like code in a separate file, and set the src of the iframe to that file. Let me know if you have quesitons

Comment: I forgot a downfall: when the like button generates its post to facebook box, it won't be visible because it's in the context of the iframe. However, this posting box usually doesn't work well for me if it even does, and I've only personally found myself using it once or twice ever.