# Understanding og:url

Tags: ios, facebook-opengraph

I am working through the Facebook tutorial for iOS and am having trouble when a get to the final part with Publish Open Graph Story.  I have gone through and set everything up as best I understand.  When I try to test using the Object Debugger I get "Missing Required Property:   The 'og:url' property is required, but not present." Can some one help me and explain this tag and how it should be set?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [ogp.me](http://ogp.me/) they define og:url as :

> og:url - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its
>   permanent ID in the graph, e.g.,
>   "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".

Basically as jeff sherlock of facebook explains in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831012/228741

That when you give the url of your action (the one containing meta tags) facebook ignores everything that is on that page (doesn't render it) . But it renders whatever you have given in the og:url.

What i do usually is have my og:url call the same page with the parameters. So facebook renders the same page for me. If you want to render some other page you give the link in the og:url.

Answer (score 0):

This is set as a meta tag in the `<head>` section.

Example :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="your url">
```