# og:href? Dynamic Facebook Meta Tag link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm building a dynamic website with backbone and I want to allow users to share links (like www.example.com/posts/1). The problem is fb crawler don't process javascript so the approach I took is I created a separate page in the backbend that purely serves the facebook meta tags.

There's a fb_meta/posts/[id] page that serves the following:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Cool post"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="test"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/posts/10"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Test site"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://test.jpg"/>
```

The problem with this was the url tag pretty much tells facebook to ignore everything on this page and process the link defined in the url tag. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830846/ogurl-is-driving-me-crazy))

So I tried the change og:url to og:href.

And cool! Facebook now reads in all my meta tags correctly and processed the images. BUT it somehow can't link the shared post to the link i defined in og:href. According to the [fb open grab debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), the href type is invalid:

"
Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:href'.

Parser Mismatched Metadata  The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input     metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:href'
"

My question is wether it's possible to let fb craw a separate meta page, and have the og meta tags to tell fb to link to the actual page?

Thanks

Comment: No it is not possible. The og-tags need to be on the url they are describing

Comment: Have you tried using JavaScript redirects? As far as I'm aware Facebook will ignore this, meaning that the scraping will work fine, but the user experience will send the user straight to where ever you want them to go.